# SSIS Archiving a file

Tags: sql-server, csv, variables, ssis, etl

I have an SSIS package that outputs a csv file what I want to do is look in the destination folder before I generate a csv and if one already exists (I produce them on a daily basis ) then move it to an archive folder.

my file name structure is "NAME_YYMMDD_HHMM.csv" I'm  not sure how I go about looking for a file as the date and time will always be different. i've created a variable for the filename "NAME_*_.csv but not sure how id add this to a file system task? if a file doesn't exist id like it to just move on to next step in package if it does exist then move file to archive folder

Comment: use a script task to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

You should use a script task to do this:

Use a variable in string file instead which holds your values from YYMMDD since HHMM is unable to get when you created it run time.

Date formats can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings)

> Use namespace using System.IO;

```
        string filepath = @"D:\new";

        string file = "test_171205_1010.txt";

        string fullpath = filepath + @"\" + file;

        string newpath = @"D:\arch\";
        string newfullpath = newpath + file;

        if(
            File.Exists(fullpath))
        {
            File.Move(fullpath, newfullpath);
        }
```

**Update**

And if you wanna use something about todays date, you can do like below where i look for all files of today and move them. Its up to your what the logic should be.

```
        string txtFile = null;
        string txtMoveFile = null;

        string date = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyMMdd");
        string filepath = @"D:\new"; 

        /*USE THIS LINE IF YOU WANNA USE VARIABLE FROM FOREACH LOOP CONTAINER*/
        string file = Dts.Variables["User::name"].Value.ToString() +"_*_*.txt";

        //string file = "test_"+date+"_*.txt";

        string[] allfilesfromcurrentdate = Directory.GetFiles(filepath, file);
        string fullpath = filepath + @"\" + file;

        string newpath = @"D:\arch\";
        string newfullpath = newpath + file;

        foreach(string fileName in allfilesfromcurrentdate)
        {
            if(fileName.Contains("test_"+date))
            {
                txtFile = fileName;
                txtMoveFile = txtFile.Replace("new", "arch");
               if(File.Exists(txtFile))
                {
                    File.Move(txtFile, txtMoveFile);
                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: Beside that, dont save your CSV files with HH and MM timestamp. Just save them by day, its a lot easier and when you only run them on daily basis its enough.

Comment: I created a variable string "name_*_*.csv, created a foreachloopcontainer with the source folder variable and the destination variable then put the following within the collection file spec "name"+"_"+"*"+"_"+"*"".csv" but this is not working I have done it this way as I am not bothered when the file was created just if one exists to move it

Comment: @sql2015 then use your variable string in the script task. Then you can find it. This here works perfectly for me. Just adjust your requirements. If your just looking for the name, then just replace string file with your variable.

Comment: @sql2015 string file = Dts.Variable["User::NAMEOFVARIABLE"].Value.Tostring() +"_ *_ *.txt";

Comment: @plaidDK you must use `string date = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyMMdd_HHmm");`

Comment: @Hadi - As i wrote to you, you cannot use HHMM because its runtime. So you wont be able to match it. Therefore i only use Date. Else it wont work. Nevertheless thats not the requirement and he only needs the filename as i wrote in my update. This will work for him.

Comment: @plaidDK ah ok, now i agree with that +1

Comment: @Hadi But else youre right :) Thanks for clarifying.